# How to call MailServlet to send mail to registered user while redirect to loginpage.jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How do I call my MailServlet to send a mail to a registered user while forwarding to the login page? This is my code snippet to go to the `loginpage.jsp` after registerSucces = true;

```
RequestDispatcher rd = null;
if (registerSucces) {
    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("loginpage.jsp");

} else {
    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("registerpage.jsp");
}
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Why do you define mail servlet? You can create an utility class to send mail. At the if condition invoke the send mail method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use MailServlet to send Emails. Because servlet act as view component. 
Send mails to users that registered successfully is a service. And service must be implemented as a normal java pojo class.

Similar to this::

```
class SendMail
{
    static send()
    {
        // logic to send mails
    }
}
```

and you should call send emails like this:

```
if (registerSucces) 
{
    SendMail.send();
    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("loginpage.jsp");
} 
else 
{
    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("registerpage.jsp");
}
rd.forward(request, response);
```